# Django Messages, How to Hide Specific Ones

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2, django-messages

I am using Django's messages framework to indicate successful actions and failed actions.

How can I exclude account sign in and sign out messages?  Currently, landing on a page after signing in displays 
`Successfully signed in as 'username'`.  I do not want this message to be displayed, but all other success messages should be displayed.  What I attempted is shown below. I tried using logic to find if the message had the word `"signed"` in it.  If it did, do not display it.  That however is not working though.

```
{% if messages %}

 <div class="db-section">
      <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}

          {% if "signed" in message %} 
            # Don't display anything
          {% else %}

          <div class="alert alert-error">

          <strong style="color:{% if 'success' in message.tags %}green{% else %} red {% endif %};padding-bottom:10px;">{{ message }}</strong>

          </div>

          {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  </div>

{% endif %}
```

Could someone possibly explain why the above code is still displaying messages that even contain `"signed"` in it?

Comment: Are you using the Jinja2 or the Django Template Language to your HTML templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `safe` filter to convert that `message` object attribute to actual string and compare

```
--- Your code ---
{% if "signed" in message|safe %} 
  # Don't display anything
{% else %}
--- Your remaining code ---
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!